# Skin Effect of resistors

Tags: high-frequency

Skin effect of metallic conductors is well documented.

What about SMD resistors?
High values Vs low values? Above what frequencies would this be an issue?

Answer (score 12):

Skin effect is well-documented and that good documentation, I believe, tells you exactly what you need to know; As a conductor's DC resistance increases, then skin effects are less noticeable. Extract from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect#Resistance): -

> In a good conductor, skin depth is proportional to square root of the
>   resistivity. This means that better conductors have a reduced skin
>   depth. The overall resistance of the better conductor remains lower
>   even with the reduced skin depth. However the better conductor will
>   show a higher ratio between its AC and DC resistance, when compared
>   with a conductor of higher resistivity. For example, at 60 Hz, a 2000
>   MCM (1000 square millimetre) copper conductor has 23% more resistance
>   than it does at DC. The same size conductor in aluminum has only 10%
>   more resistance with 60 Hz AC than it does with DC.[9]

Comment: And, I'm pleased to announce that the phantom downvoter has struck again. Yippee!

Comment: +1 for stating that skin effect is more pronounced for good conducters .So does this mean that resistors should be not too bad  in this respect ?

Comment: Resistors above a few ohms should barely have any noticeable skin effects especially if the resistors are smaller than the predicted skin thickness.

Comment: @Andyaka Welcome to the stack exchange sites, where your questions (and answers!) are down-voted before you've even finished typing!